# Harmonic conjugate of $u,v$ in $f=u+iv$

Tags: complex-analysis, definition, harmonic-functions

Do I understand correctly the definition of being harmonic conjugate
if I understand it that:

$v$ is the harmonic conjugate of $u$

but
$u$ is not the harmonic conjugate of $v$, but rather $-u$ ?

Comment: Yes, multiply the equation by $-i$ and $-if = v - iu$ and so you should say $-u$ is the conjugate of $v$.

Comment: @muzzlator - thanks! I tried doing this with C-R equations, but it was confusing and I wanted to make sure. your way is a nice one! (and you can post it as an answer if you would like to)

Comment: no probs, CR equation kind of nice to see why it all works if you don't already know that multiplication by a constant preserves the CR equation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, multiply the equation by $−i$ and $−if=v−iu$ and so you should say $−u$ is the conjugate of $v$.